# How to filter duplicate and non-duplicate dates on documents mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I've been working on agregation in the past days but I could not figure out how to filter documents with the same dates.

Here are the documents. At the moment, there are 5 of them.

Index `0` and index `1` has the same date and Index `2` and index `3` has the same date

The idea is, filter those documents with the same date and total the `start` and `end` on each filtered objects

Here is the full [exported](https://file.io/TUv8r41LpLXg) documents from the mongodb

```js
 [
  {
    _id: "63df0b216557e49cd48d0399",
    start: "2023-02-05T01:49:21.677Z",
    isWorking: false,
    createdAt: "2023-02-05T01:49:21.789Z",
    updatedAt: "2023-02-05T01:49:28.109Z",
    end: "2023-02-05T01:49:28.010Z",
  },
  {
    _id: "63df0ad16557e49cd48d0390",
    start: "2023-02-05T01:48:01.843Z",
    isWorking: false,
    createdAt: "2023-02-05T01:48:01.936Z",
    updatedAt: "2023-02-05T01:48:06.355Z",
    end: "2023-02-05T01:48:06.272Z",
  },
  {
    _id: "63df0d1d47e5e303ef3f1987",
    start: "2023-02-04T01:57:08.230Z",
    isWorking: false,
    createdAt: "2023-02-04T01:57:08.230Z",
    updatedAt: "2023-02-04T01:57:08.230Z",
    end: "2023-02-04T01:57:42.900Z",
  },
  {
    _id: "63df0cc247e5e303ef3f1986",
    start: "2023-02-04T01:55:15.091Z",
    isWorking: false,
    createdAt: "2023-02-04T01:55:15.091Z",
    updatedAt: "2023-02-04T01:55:15.091Z",
    end: "2023-02-04T01:56:12.035Z",
  },
  {
    _id: "63df0d5147e5e303ef3f1988",
    start: "2023-02-03T01:58:18.018Z",
    isWorking: false,
    createdAt: "2023-02-03T01:58:18.018Z",
    updatedAt: "2023-02-03T01:58:18.018Z",
    end: "2023-02-03T01:58:35.941Z",
  },
];
```

Comment: It's not completely clear what you mean. Can you also provide the exact output that you want, given the input you have showed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set` to avoid duplicate datas.
Get additional information about `Sets` from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentation and watching a lot of tutorials, I think I solved it but I won't mark this as an answer yet because I know there will be some edits for this solution.

```js
const entries = await entryModel.aggregate( [
{
  $addFields: {
    day: {
      $dayOfMonth: '$createdAt'
    },
    calcStartAndEnd: {
      $dateDiff: {
        startDate: '$start',
        endDate: '$end',
        unit: 'millisecond'
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: '$day',
    numOfDocs: { $sum: 1 },
    docs: {
      $push: {
        _id: '$_id',
        start: '$start',
        end: '$end',
        total: '$calcStartAndEnd',
        createdAt: '$createdAt'
      }
    },
  }
},
] )
```

This is the result.

```js
[
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "numOfDocs": 1,
      "docs": [
        {
          "_id": "63df0d5147e5e303ef3f1988",
          "start": "2023-02-03T01:58:18.018Z",
          "end": "2023-02-03T01:58:35.941Z",
          "total": 17923,
          "createdAt": "2023-02-03T01:58:18.018Z"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 6,
      "numOfDocs": 1,
      "docs": [
        {
          "_id": "63e0fc4e7b2f0f3faf7cc9f2",
          "start": "2023-02-06T13:10:38.501Z",
          "total": null,
          "createdAt": "2023-02-06T13:10:38.555Z"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 4,
      "numOfDocs": 2,
      "docs": [
        {
            "_id": "63df0cc247e5e303ef3f1986",
            "start": "2023-02-04T01:55:15.091Z",
            "end": "2023-02-04T01:56:12.035Z",
            "total": 56944,
            "createdAt": "2023-02-04T01:55:15.091Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "63df0d1d47e5e303ef3f1987",
            "start": "2023-02-04T01:57:08.230Z",
            "end": "2023-02-04T01:57:42.900Z",
            "total": 34670,
            "createdAt": "2023-02-04T01:57:08.230Z"
        }
      ]
    },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "numOfDocs": 2,
    "docs": [
      {
          "_id": "63df0ad16557e49cd48d0390",
          "start": "2023-02-05T01:48:01.843Z",
          "end": "2023-02-05T01:48:06.272Z",
          "total": 4429,
          "createdAt": "2023-02-05T01:48:01.936Z"
      },
      {
          "_id": "63df0b216557e49cd48d0399",
          "start": "2023-02-05T01:49:21.677Z",
          "end": "2023-02-05T01:49:28.010Z",
          "total": 6333,
          "createdAt": "2023-02-05T01:49:21.789Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```